# How to install using pip a namespace package that uses pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, package, python-3.9, pyproject.toml

Currently I'm working on a project for which I need to install a namespace package that was designed/written for `pdm` (https://pdm.fming.dev/) and uses `pyproject.toml`

Project that needs that namespace package can only install packages using pip and I keep getting this error when I run `python3 pip install git+ssh://link_to_package_on_github@main#egg=package_name`:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement { package-name } (unavailable) (from versions: 1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for { package-name } (unavailable)
```

`pyproject.toml` looks something like this:

```
[project]
name = project-name
version = { use_scm = true }

requires-python = ">=3.9"
dynamic = [
    "classifiers",
    "version"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
[build-system]
requires = ["pdm-pep517"]
build-backend = "pdm.pep517.api"

[tool]
[tool.pdm]
package-dir = "src"
includes = [ "calc" ]
```

Directory structure of the namespace package (no `setup.py` / `setup.cfg` / `__init__.py`):\

```
project-name/ \
– src/ \
–– package-name/ \
––– module.py \
– pyproject.toml
```

**Question:**
is there a way to install a namespace package that uses pyproject.toml using pip? how do i modify my code/configurations to do it?

NOTE:
Python 3.9.7 is used all across
pip is up to date

Comment: Seems like you might be confusing the installable project name and the importable package name. If the name of the project is `project-name` (as seems to be the case), then you need to install as `git+ssh://link_to_package_on_github@main#egg=project_name`, note the `egg` part, but probably you can simply omit the `egg` part in this case.

Comment: hmm, you're right thanks! but for some reason it only works in `--editable` mode, otherwise the `direct_url.json` file points to the github repo and the package is not importable, any idea why?

Comment: No idea. Maybe more details could help figure out what is happening.